# iOS rounding UIView corners with draw enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, draw, rounded-corners

When `draw` method is commented out inside the below code the view shows up circular, but when it is uncommented out the view shows up as a rectangle again. I could comment out the body of `draw` to have it just be an empty method, but the view would still show up as a rectangle.

I've tried moving the `cornerRadius` line to the end of `draw`, beginning of `draw`, and end of `drawInnerCircle` but to no avail. I was wondering if there was still a way to make the view rounded with `draw` method enabled?

```
import UIKit
class IconView: UIView {

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 47/255, green: 49/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2.0
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawInnerCircle()
    }

    internal func drawInnerCircle() -> () {
        let halfSize:CGFloat = min( self.frame.size.width/2, bounds.size.height/2)
        let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = 1    // your desired value
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: CGPoint(x:halfSize,y:halfSize),
            radius: CGFloat( halfSize - 3 ),
            startAngle: CGFloat(0),
            endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2),
            clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 96/255, green: 99/255, blue: 105/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = desiredLineWidth
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to give the `shapeLayer ` corner also?

Comment: The shapeLayer is an inner circle so it has technically no corners

Comment: Dear stumped, currently you do always add a new layer to your view, when it is redrawn (which might happen pretty often). Please either remove the old layer or keep the "old" layer in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following:

> self.layer.masksToBounds = true

below the line:

> self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2.0

By the way there are some problem described by the above comments.